# rails getting different result in test and development and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am testing my app with rails t.

I get there the result `Object.count == 1`.

When I run my app in browser, I am having `Object.count == 2`.

How could that happen?

I think I have the same input in both cases.

It is a model.

Comment: The "Object" you are referring to is that a Model or object of some class

Comment: Well, dev, test and production have separate databases. Not sure why that should be surprising.

Comment: The Test passes with model Object.count == 1. This is the behavior I want.

Comment: When I try to see if the app works correctly in the browser, I simulate the same input and see that two objects are created instead of one. So I have the same input but get different results. I tried to find different entries in configs files but without success.

Comment: See "[mcve]" and particularly Jon Skeet's "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"

Answer (score -2):

I found the error. The input was different.